# how to tweak a sentences in a column using php laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

hey so currently i have a database with a column call sampleQ1 in the column its examples of question. So one of the question is: 'What documents are required when I wish to apply for ?' I want to know how can i call this question i a page then enable a user to tweak the ? Is there a way?? currently there is another function that i have done to get the value of  i just wanna know how to swap  with the value?

currently how im calling the sentences is as below:

controller:

```html
public function newTest($companyID, $entityType,$q)
 {
  $db = [];
  $dmb = DiraMasterBot::all();
  foreach ($dmb AS $datum) 
  { 
   if (!isset($db[$datum->description])) $db[$datum->description] = ['intent' => [], 'q1' => [], 'q2' => [], 'q3' => []]; 
   $db[$datum->description]['intent'][$datum->intent] = $datum->id; 

   if (!isset($db[$datum->description])) $db[$datum->description] = ['intent' => [], 'q1' => [], 'q2' => [], 'q3' => []]; 
   $db[$datum->description]['q1'][$datum->sampleQ1] = $datum->id; 

   if (!isset($db[$datum->description])) $db[$datum->description] = ['intent' => [], 'q1' => [], 'q2' => [], 'q3' => []]; 
   $db[$datum->description]['q2'][$datum->sampleQ2] = $datum->id; 

   if (!isset($db[$datum->description])) $db[$datum->description] = ['intent' => [], 'q1' => [], 'q2' => [], 'q3' => []]; 
   $db[$datum->description]['q3'][$datum->sampleQ3] = $datum->id; 
  } 

  ksort($db);
  // dd($db);

  return view('AltHr.Chatbot.newTest', compact('db', 'dmb','entityType','companyID','q'));
 }
```

view:

```html
@foreach($questionAnswer['q2'] as $question => $questionID)
                      <table class="question">
                        <tr>
                          <td class="labels"><p>User:</p></td>
                          <td><p>&nbsp;{{$question}}</p></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                      @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer to it which is using

```html
<?php
  echo str_replace("world","Peter","Hello world!");
?>
```